# natcasesort($array) returns boolean instead of array?

Tags: php, arrays

In the function below, I'm seeing to sort the array by alpha. However, it returns bool(true) rather than the actual sorted array. What am I missing?

```
function get_dirs($dir) {
    $array = array();
    $d = dir($dir);
    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())){
        if($entry!='.' && $entry!='..') {
            $entry2 = $dir."/".$entry;
            if(is_dir($entry2)) {
                $array[] = $entry;
            }
        }
    }
    $d->close();
    //return $array; THIS WORKS FINE BUT UNSORTED
    return natcasesort($array); //THIS RETURNS A BOOLEAN?
    }
```

Comment: Yes, because it returns a boolean! http://php.net/natcasesort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`natcasesort` returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Change

```
return natcasesort($array);
```

to

```
natcasesort($array);
return $array;
```

Answer (score 2):

That function returns TRUE/FALSE on success/failure.  The original variable will be sorted.

```
$d->close();
if(natcasesort($array)) return $array;
else return false;
```

Check out the documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As the manual says:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Have a look at the function signature in the manual page:

> bool natcasesort ( array &$array )

The `&` sign means "reference", so `$array` is modified, rather than a new array being returned.  This is the same as all (IIRC) PHP sorting functions.

You should do the sort and *then* return `$array`:

```
natcasesort($array);
return $array;
```

Answer (score 1):

natcasesort sorts the array and returns true on success and false if it fails. Solve it by sorting the array and then returning it.

```
natcasesort($array);
return $array;
```